EF Core 8 JSON column mapping
I am having difficulty setting up a JSON column with my EF Core 8 setup. I have the following code:
public class CategoryVersion
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public Category Category { get; set; } = null!;
    public required DateTime ValidfromUTC { get; set; }
    public required LanguageField Name { get; set; }
    public required LanguageField Description { get; set; }
    public required CategoryAttributes Attributes { get; set; }

    public void UpdateFromRequest(UpdateCategoryVersionRequest updateRequest)
    {
        ValidfromUTC = updateRequest.ValidfromUTC;
        Name = updateRequest.Name;
        Description = updateRequest.Description;
        Attributes.UpdateFromDto(updateRequest.Attributes);
    }
}

public class CategoryVersionConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<CategoryVersion>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<CategoryVersion> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("CategoryVersions");
        builder.HasOne(v => v.Category);
        builder.HasOne(v => v.Attributes);
        builder.OwnsOne(v => v.Name, langField =>
        {
            langField.ToJson();
            langField.OwnsMany(n => n.Translations, translations =>
            {
                translations.Property(t => t.Language);
                translations.Property(t => t.Value);
            });
        });
        builder.OwnsOne(v => v.Description, langField =>
        {
            langField.ToJson();
            langField.OwnsMany(n => n.Translations, translations =>
            {
                translations.Property(t => t.Language);
                translations.Property(t => t.Value);
            });
        });
    }
}

public class LanguageField
{
    public List<Translation> Translations { get; } = [];

    public void AddTranslation(string language, string value)
    {
        Translations.Add(new Translation(language, value));
    }

    public string? GetTranslation(string language)
    {
        var translation = Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Language == language)?.Value;
        return translation ?? null;
    }
}


public class Translation
{
    public Translation(string language, string value)
    {
        Language = language;
        Value = value;
    }

    public string Language { get; private set; }
    public string Value { get; private set; }
}


I send in the following payload in Swagger:
{
    "validfromUTC": "2024-04-23T12:21:34.381Z",
    "name": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "value": "Wine"
            },
            {
                "language": "sv",
                "value": "Vin"
            }
        ]
    },
    "description": {
        "translations": [
            {
                "language": "eng",
                "value": "Wine"
            },
            {
                "language": "sv",
                "value": "Vin"
            }
        ]
    },
    "attributes": {
        "color": "string",
        "allowDiscount": true,
        "allowLoyalty": true,
        "ageRestriction": 0,
        "isDelegate": true
    }
}

And this is the response I get:

{
  "id": "03888d60-bdac-48ac-1c2e-08dc64845a13",
  "validfromUTC": "2024-04-23T12:21:34.381Z",
  "name": {
    "translations": []
  },
  "description": {
    "translations": []
  },
  "attributes": {
    "color": "string",
    "allowDiscount": true,
    "allowLoyalty": true,
    "ageRestriction": 0,
    "isDelegate": true
  }
}

What am I missing? Why is EF Core not mapping the Translations to JSON? I am using a local DB running in a Docker container, image mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge.
I have tried using a List but also a Dictionary<string, string> to get this to work but haven't managed to configure it correctly.

Create the entity in code and return it to the client.  Compare that JSON with the JSON you are sending to your controller.
